# Why does python's os.stat() tell me my file group is empty?

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.6.4 on Solaris 5-10.

I have a file named "myFile". It is owned by someone else, by I ("myuser") am in the file's group ("mygrp"). Below is my python code. Why does it tell me that mygrp has no members???

```
>>> import os, pwd, grp 
>>> stat_info = os.stat("myFile") 
>>> fileUID = stat_info.st_uid 
>>> fileGID = stat_info.st_gid 
>>> fileGroup = grp.getgrgid(fileGID)[0] 
>>> fileUser = pwd.getpwuid(fileUID)[0] 
>>> print "grp.getgrgid(fileGID) = %s" % grp.getgrgid(fileGID) 
grp.getgrgid(fileGID) = grp.struct_group(gr_name='mygrp', gr_passwd='', gr_gid=100, gr_mem=[])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html) (emphasis mine):

> The gid is an integer, name and password are strings, and the member list is a list of strings. (**Note that most users are not explicitly listed as members of the group they are in according to the password database. Check both databases to get complete membership information.** Also note that a gr_name that starts with a + or - is likely to be a YP/NIS reference and may not be accessible via getgrnam() or getgrgid().)

That might explain why you're not listed in the results, even though you're a member of that group. I believe you'd have to use [`pwd.getpwall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html#module-pwd) and filter it for the group id to get the rest of the members of that group.

**Update:** Explaining further, according to the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.python/yzeXZRLRnWY) the OP posted in the comments:

> Every account has a primary group, and some accounts also
>   have addtional groups.  The primary group is the one in the
>   .pw_gid attribute in the pwd entry.  The additional groups
>   are those that mention the account in the .gr_mem attribute
>   in their grp entry.

Example code to retrieve all members of a group:

```
def all_members(gid):
    primary_members = [user.pw_name for user in pwd.getpwall() if user.pw_gid == gid]
    additional_members = grp.getgrgid(gid).gr_mem
    return primary_members + additional_members
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Someone else also gave me the same advice and it worked: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.python/yzeXZRLRnWY